# isset() and PHP global variables

Tags: php, function, variables, global-variables

Regarding global variable initialization,

```
function hello_testing() {
    global $conditional_random;
    if (isset($conditional_random)) {
        echo "foo is inside";
    }
}
```

The global variable (conditional_random) may not be initialized before the `hello_testing()` function is called.

So, what happens to my validation via `isset()` when `$conditional_random` is not initialized? Will it fail or it will always be true?

Comment: On a side note try to stay away from global. It's a sure sign of spaghetti code

Comment: @Manos I agree, but if you develop in the Wordpress community (as one example) it's more or less impossible to stay away from global variables or a number of other bad conventions. To my mind, if you're working with PHP in the first place, you've resigned yourself to tolerating poor coding practices and just need to know relatively safe ways to work with what you've got.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Well, why don't you just test ? ;-)

**Note:** It is not as easy as you'd think -- read the full answer ;-)

Calling the `hello_testing();` function, without setting the variable:

```
hello_testing();
```

I get no output -- which indicates [**`isset`**](https://www.php.net/isset) returned **`false`**.

Calling the function, after setting the variable:

```
$conditional_random = 'blah';
hello_testing();
```

I get an output:

```
foo is inside
```

Which indicates [`global`](http://fr.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php) works as expected, when the variable is set *-- well, one should not have any doubt about that ^^*

---

**But note that `isset` will return `false` if a variable is set, and `null`!**

See the [**manual page of `isset()`**](https://www.php.net/isset)

Which means that a better test would be:

```
function hello_testing() {
    global $conditional_random;
    var_dump($conditional_random);
}

hello_testing();
```

And this displays:

```
null
```

No Notice: the variable exists! Even if `null`.

As I didn't set the variable outside of the function, it shows that `global` *sets* the variable -- but it doesn't put a value into it; which means it's `null` if not already set outside the function.

While:

```
function hello_testing() {
    //global $conditional_random;
    var_dump($conditional_random);
}

hello_testing();
```

Gives:

```
Notice: Undefined variable: conditional_random
```

It proves that notices are enabled ;-)

And, if global didn't "*set*" the variable, the previous example would have given the same notice.

And, finally:

```
function hello_testing() {
    global $conditional_random;
    var_dump($conditional_random);
}

$conditional_random = 'glop';
hello_testing();
```

Gives:

```
string 'glop' (length=4)
```

*(This is to purely to demonstrate my example is not tricked ^^)*

Comment: So your 'test' is to see if a notice is triggered? While the explanation of how isset works is good, this doesn't seem provide a useful alternative.

Comment: Excellent explanation and demonstration, global will decalre the variable as null if not decalred outside the funcion. Exaclty the answer I was looking for, Thanks!

Answer (score 11):

You can check to see if the global has been created by checking if the key exists in $GLOBALS:

```
echo array_key_exists('fooBar', $GLOBALS) ? "true\n" : "false\n";
// Outputs false

global $fooBar;

echo array_key_exists('fooBar', $GLOBALS) ? "true\n" : "false\n";
// Outputs true

echo isset($fooBar) ? "true\n" : "false\n";
// Outputs false
```

This is the only way I know of to check the existence of a global without triggering a warning.

As Manos Dilaverakis mentioned, you should avoid using globals whenever possible.

Answer (score 1):

**SOLUTION 1**

No need to use any function. If a global variable is not set, it will result as `null`, and `null` is equal to `false` in PHP statements. So you can use something like this and it will work:

```
global $GLOBAL_VARIABLE;
if ($GLOBAL_VARIABLE) {
  // Global variable exists
} else  {
  // Global variable does not exists
}
```

**SOLUTION 2**

```
if (isset($GLOBALS["name"])) {
  // Global variable "name" exists
} else  {
  // Global variable does not exists
}
```

Answer (score -2):

`Global` sets the variable. Therefore `isset($some_globald_variable)` will always return true.

The better option is `empty()`:

```
 if(empty($globald_variable))
 {
     // Variable is not set
 }
```

Comment: don't want to sound like an arse :) but you forgot one parenthesis in your `if` statement :)

Comment: The variable does get created, but it's initialized as null. isset returns false given a variable with a null value.

Comment: This answer is quite incorrect. In addition to what @goat said, the 'empty' function will return true for false-like values such as '', [ ], 0, false