# What are the characteristics of spaghetti code?

Tags: php, wordpress, coding-style

Somebody said that when your PHP code and application use global variables then it must be  spaghetti code (I assume this). I use WordPress a lot. As far as I know, it's the best thing near great PHP software. And it uses many global variables to interact between its components.

But forget about that, because frankly, that's the only thing I know. So it's completely biased ;D

**So, I am just curious, What is the characteristic of spaghetti code?**

PS: the only thing I know is WordPress. So, hopefully, maybe this will help somebody give a great answer for somebody who has little experience in developing a full web application on PHP (for example, the Stack Overflow website).

Comment: what do you mean under `global variable`?

Comment: i meant in this comment in  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2571474/isset-and-php-global-variable

Comment: Wordpress is one of the **worst** examples of PHP programming in the mainstream, and the main reason is that they rely extremely heavily on global variables. They have a terrible reputation for security because of it.  I'd post examples of why it's bad, but I already wrote a long rant about it (http://www.phpvs.net/2009/12/08/an-exercise-in-wordpress-integration-or-why-wordpress-sucks/).  If you want to get experience building PHP web applications, I'd suggest looking into some of the PHP frameworks out there, such as Zend, Symfony or CodeIgniter.

Comment: @zombat Codeigniter isn't exactly pretty either. @justjoe have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2571078/ and my answer for an example on how to improve spaghetti code.

Comment: *(reference)* http://sourcemaking.com/antipatterns/spaghetti-code

Comment: +1 great reference...

@gordon : thanks, it's really really helpful. At least, to some extent, it's enlighten me. Even though, i still confuse by the jargon and jokes. ;D

Comment: @Gordon - 100% agree.  Codeigniter had to do some ugly stuff to achieve backwards compatibility with PHP4, and the internal code is pretty messy.  However, it has a reasonably straightforward API and decent documentation, so it's a lot easier to *make* decent code with it.  That being said, I don't use it myself anymore ;)

Comment: "I use WordPress a lot. As far as I know, it's the best thing near great PHP software." -- I lol'd. Wordpress is notoriously terrible in terms of software coding standards. It's the finest example of spaghetti code that I can think of.

Comment: http://www.ptidej.net/research/designsmells/materials/TextualDescriptionOfSpaghettiCode.pdf

Answer (score 25, accepted):

- No modularity (everything in one file, class, module, namespace, package, or whatever your language uses to provide modularity),
- Plenty of `goto`'s,
- Poor organization,
- No clear separation of functionality and purpose. (That is, all-encompassing classes or functions)
- Long functions.
- Poor naming.
- No consistent coding style throughout.
- No clear interface contract between implementation and clients of code. (That is, no specification of what the inputs, outputs, pre- and post-conditions of functions are)
- Over-reliance on internals of data structures with little abstraction.
- Functions randomly permute/modify global state without any mention of it in documentation.
- Lack of comments or documentation of non-trivial code.
- Code that is more complicated than it needs to be.
- Lack of reuse. (plenty of duplicated code, a.k.a. [copypasta](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=copypasta))
- No verification or unit testing (it works on faith).
- Magic numbers.

In essence, a lack of design and
forethought, and just a mishmash of
hacks slapped together. This applies to any language, not just PHP.

> for somebody who has little experience in developing a full web application on PHP (for example, the Stack Overflow website)

Just FYI, but Stack Overflow was not developed with PHP.

Comment: @alex : what ? i assume every web in this world develop using PHP ;D

Comment: Guess we found the one that doesn't!

Answer (score 8):

Well, talking of comment you posted, the explanation is very simple. 
Using `global` operator makes source of a variable is unknown, like other end of spaghetti noodle. It can be defined everywhere. So, when you call your function, you have no idea what value this variable has. Instead of it, direct passing a variable makes it plain and clear:

```
function hello_testing($conditional_random) {
  if ($conditional_random)) {
      echo "foo is inside";  
  }
}
```

P.S. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spaghetti_code

Comment: Well.. it's not just that it's source is unknown, but it's not properly encapsulated. If you start throwing everything to global space, you start getting name clashes, and other problems...

Answer (score 6):

Spaghetti code has specific characteristics which distinguish it from plain poor code.  Spaghetti is extremely complicated and unstructured, so it is hard to follow the flow of a process through the program.  It is like trying to untangle the noodles in a bowl of *bolognese*.

This is why `GOTO` statements (dread word!) are often cited in this context: a `GOTO` statement transfers control to another arbitrarily defined location in the code base.  Most programming languages have commands which can be abused to simulate `goto` style behaviour; for instance, using exceptions to implement regular business logic rather than handling errors.

Global variables contribute to spaghetti code because the values are assigned outside of the scope of the current program unit.  This can make it difficult to determine where in the code base a variable is set to a given value (or indeed whether it is set to any value at all).

Spaghetti code can be functionally correct and performative. It's a problem because it's hard to understand, so we can't be sure it is bug free and the lack of structure makes it difficult to troubleshoot. For similar reasons spaghetti code is brittle and difficult to change; the risk of introducing a bug is high.

Incidentally, the use of `goto` statements does not mean a program is spaghetti.  It is perfectly possible to write clear, well-structured code using `goto`, it is just requires a lot of self-discipline not to abuse its flexibility.   Modern programming languages have made its use unnecessary, and undesirable.

Answer (score 3):

[WordPress](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WordPress) is the biggest piece of spaghetti code PHP I have seen around.  There is a shocking mix of PHP, HTML, JavaScript and all things in between all lumped in the same files.  If you want another example of spaghetti code look at [osCommerce](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OsCommerce) or [Zen Cart](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zen_Cart).

In fact I dare say a large majority of open source PHP applications are pretty shocking examples of how to program in PHP.  If you want to look at a good structured example (that is, non-spaghetti) then look at [Yii](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yii) framework or [Zend Framework](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zend_Framework). Frameworks like [CodeIgniter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Codeigniter#CodeIgniter) and [Kohana](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kohana), although not spaghetti, are not very good examples of how to structure things in PHP 5 as they use many of the features used in PHP 4 simply because there was no better way of doing them until PHP 5 (for example, using path based inheritance instead of true object inheritance).

If you want a reasonbly good example of procedural programming done right look at [Drupal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drupal).  It might not be the best performing PHP application, because of the complexity, but it sure beats WordPress and you can do many of the same things with it.

Comment: But Kohana was designed for PHP5 and since day one has required it, which counters what you say about it not being structured for PHP5. As for WordPress, although not MVC, which I guess is a disappointment, yes, is a remarkable thing because oddly enough it is easy customizable and rethemed. It's one of the factors why it's got more Alexa hits than Drupal, I'd dare say. Without a doubt, Drupal is harder to retheme and customize than WordPress, if you're new to these things. I've done both, and started with Drupal.

Comment: -1 for the incorrect information about Kohana. This framework is one of the best PHP examples around in terms of structure, coding style, etc. Although it was initially based on Code Igniter, it's now completely different from it.